# how can i modify a freemarker variable value inside a success block in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, freemarker

how can i change a value of a freemarker variable inside a success block in jQuery AJAX, i have two controllers for my page the first one returns me a simple string with the name of the view  with a GET method, the second one is the one that process the data using a json with a POST method

here they are

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myform", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String formmethod(Model model) {



        model.addAttribute("successMessage", "i'm in the firts controller");

        return "forms/myform";
    }
```

my second controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myform", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String getTags(@RequestBody final String json, Model model) 
    throws IOException 
    {
         ObjectMapper mapper  =  new ObjectMapper();

         User userMapped=  mapper.readValue(json, User.class);

         User person  =  new Usuario();
         person.setName("new name");
         person.setLastName("new lastname");


         model.addAttribute("successMessage", person.getName());

         return toJson(userMapped);
    }
```

my to Json method

```
private String toJson(User person) 
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try 
        {
            String value = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
            // return "["+value+"]";
            return value;
        } 
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and my page myform.html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function doAjaxPost() 
        {
            // get the form values
            var name= $('#name').val();
            var lastName = $('#lastName ').val();

            var json = {"name" : name, "lastName " : lastName };
            console.log(json);
            var FreeMarkervariable = "${successMessage}";

            //this brings me the value that i put in the firts controller


            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "myform",
                data: JSON.stringify(json), 

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,

                beforeSend: function(xhr) 
                            {
                                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
                                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
                            },
                success: function(data) 
                        {


//HERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE VALUE OF MY FREEMARKER VARIABLE SO I CAN 
//PRINT A SUCCESS MESSAGE IN A DIV


                            <#assign successMessage = "success">



                        },
                error:function(data,status,er) { 
                    alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
                }

            });
        }
</script>
    <!-- NEW WIDGET START -->
    <article class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="alert alert-warning fade in">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                ×
            </button>
            <i class="fa-fw fa fa-warning"></i>
            <strong>${successMessage} I WANT TO PRINT A SUCCESS MESSAGE HERE </strong> 
        </div>
    </article>
    <!-- WIDGET END -->
<fieldset>
 <legend>Name in view</legend>
    <form name="myform">
        Name in view:   <input type="text"   name="name">
        <br>
        Last Name in view:   <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Add Users" onclick="doAjaxPost()">

    </form>
</fieldset>
 <br>
```

so far my freemarker variable gets the value that i put inside the success block but it appears "success" before i press my submit button, i believed that the succes block was executed after i hit the submit button so i dont know why it have the value even before i press the button it should have "i'm in the firts controller" before i press the submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freemarker generates it's output on the server and this is then sent to the browser. The browser never sees any of the freemarker 'code'. You need to update the strong element using javascript/jQuery.

So instead of your <#assign...> use something like this

```
$("strong").text("Success");
```

Comment: thanks so what you saying is that it doesnt matter where i put my fremarker code, if i put it inside a javascript "if" or inside a success block, that code is going to be execute anyways?

Comment: That's right. The FreeMarker is processed on the server and the result is sent to the browser, then the javascript is processed in the browser. The browser/js don't know anything about FM. Once you understand it, FM is an excellent tool.